# Vue bind url not functioning properly with image src

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <b-container >
      <b-row>
        <div class="product">
          <img src='./assets/SocksG.jpg' alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="cart">
          <button @click="addToCart">Add To Cart</button>
          <br>
          <p>Cart({{cart}})</p>
        </div>
        <div v-for="variant in variants" 
          :key="variant.variantId"
          class="color-box"
          :style="{backgroundColor:variant.variantColor}"
          @mouseover ="updateProduct(variant.variantImage)"
          >
        </div>
      </b-row>
    </b-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      cart: 0,
      variants: [{
        variantId: 2234,
        variantColor: 'green',
        variantImage: './assets/SocksG.jpg'
      }, {
        variantId: 2235,
        variantColor: 'blue',
        variantImage: './assets/SocksB.jpg'
      }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addToCart() {
      this.cart += 1
    },
    updateProduct(variantImage) {
      this.image = variantImage
    }
  }
}
```

At first I applied `:src` to the `socksG` image and in the script I had to use `img:require("./assets/SocksG.jpg"` and it worked.

Now with the  `@mouseover` event handler that's supposed to activate the `updateProduct()` function, I get the feeling that I'm doing something wrong with the Vue url handler that should fetch the `variantImage`(s) because when I use the Vue devtools the image url is `img/SocksG.jpg` and not `./assets/SocksG.jpg`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a data property for `image`:

```js
return {
   image: ...,  // Set some initial image filename here
   cart: 0,
   ...
}
```

Use `require` like this:

```html
<img :src="require('@/assets/' + this.image)" alt="">
```

and remove the paths from the urls:

```js
variantImage: 'SocksG.jpg'
...
variantImage: 'SocksB.jpg'
```

Now the image `src` is bound to `this.image`, which you are changing with the mouseover.

Comment: The mouseover event activates the function updateProduct which is in charge of toggling the image as the mouse goes over two different color boxes

Comment: The mouseover event sets `this.image`, a variable which is 1) currently not declared and 2) not used in the template.  The answer tells you how to fix that.

Comment: Thanks @Dan  I'm such an idiot , I almost edited the whole post because i didn't think you answer was right , then  I tried it and it worked. But why doesn't it work as intended though ? `<img :src="imageSrc">` as on the vue docs site [ https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind ]

Comment: You're welcome. That happens a lot I think, way to catch it.  When you use project images in the Vue CLI, Webpack renames them in the live version.  The CLI invisibly fixes this when using `img src` if you use the string in the template, but when you bind, it needs `require` to get the right name.